# Search Wikipedia, get the first paragraph of the first entry found in all available languages using C#?

Tags: c#, wikipedia, linq-to-wiki

Suppose, I have a list of sightseeings in one language and want to enrich this list with some data from Wikipedia.

So, I have the following data -- city is Munich and it has the following attractions:

- Frauenkirche
- Marienplatz
- Karlsplatz

I need to perform the following:

1. Send a query to Wikipedia in the given language (this case it is German, for it is more likely that German wiki has a respective article).
2. Once the article is found I want to get its page title and first 2-3 paragraphs.
3. I want to strip-down any Wiki-markup and get only the text.
4. It would be nice to have the text of this article along with the title in the original ("de") and in some other languages.

I tried Linq-to-Wiki from NuGet Repository, but I can't get this scenario to run... Here is my code that justly times out:

```
var enwiki = new Wiki("LinqToWiki.Samples", "en.wikipedia.org", "/w/api.php");
var result = enwiki.Query.allpages()
              .Pages
              .Select (
              page =>
              new
              {
                Title = page.info.title,
                Text = page.revisions()
                        .Where( r => r.section == "0")
                        .Select( r => r.value)

              );
```

Comment: I think the biggest problem you're going to have is to find out which article exactly do you want, because there are many Frauenkirches and a couple of Karlsplatzes. For example, it would help if you knew that what you want is in [Category:Visitor attractions in Munich](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Visitor_attractions_in_Munich) or its subcategories.

Comment: Also: yay, first question about my library! (I am the author of LinqToWiki.)

Comment: I agree about the problem to find out the correct title. Unfortunately the only information I have is the city, the approximate name of the place and the GPS coordinates. But I use just `.Query.search()` in the first step to perform a full-text search and find potential articles. How would the knowledge of a category help me here? How can I benefit from it?

Comment: And wow, it is really commendable for an author to provide an instant support of his libraries here, hats off!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the titles of the articles in question, you can do something like:

```
var titles = wiki.CreateTitlesSource(
    "Munich Frauenkirche", "Marienplatz", "Karlsplatz (Stachus)");
var pages =
    titles.Select(
        page => new
        {
            Title = page.info.title,
            Text = page.revisions()
                       .Where(r => r.section == "0" && r.parse)
                       .Select(r => r.value)
                       .FirstOrDefault(),
            LangLinks = page.langlinks().ToEnumerable()
        }).ToEnumerable();
```

`LangLinks` will contain titles of the article in different languages.

`Text` will contain HTML of the first section. If you think wikitext would be better, you could get that instead by removing `&& r.parse`.

There is also `extracts` module that seems to support getting actual plaintext, but that module is currently not supported by LinqToWiki.

Comment: I tried to figure it out on my own, but without success: is there a way to fill `LangLinks` with language code and first paragraph of an article in this language (so,basically it is `Dictionary<string,string>')

Comment: @AlexanderGalkin There isn't. If you want to get the text of an article on some wiki, you need to use the API of that wiki, which means you would need to create a separate `Wiki` object for each and use that.